# Can anyone tell me how to add list view to the other calendar(public calendar) or how to share my calendar?

Tags: calendar, lightning-scheduler

Picture for the problem statement

[image: custom calendar image]

Comment: Do the steps in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.calendar_sharing_view_lex.htm&type=5)  help?  OWD Sharing Settings of Calendar Object should be set as Show Details and Add Events so each of the Users can share their calendar with other users

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/356915/104429
This approach can also be used to add Public calendars to other users CalendarViews.